# Category Specific Catalog Rule

Tags: magento-enterprise, catalog-price-rules

I need to setup a discount for one specific category products , but need to show discount only on that category page. So in case if the same product is assign to any other category, it should not display the discounted price.
I tried all the way but it seem impossible with Default Magento.
Can anyone suggest me the way to achieve this type of functionality?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

These are both low-tech solutions:

You will have to set up a **separate product** and apply the discount to that product, specifically. You will then merchandise that product into the category and **remove the standard version** of the product. This allows you to use Catalog Pricing Rules.

If this is undesirable (and I can see why it would be) the only other alternative is to **add messaging** (call to action / coupon code, etc.) to the category page in question with widgets or custom layout update XML.

If you have Enterprise Edition, you can add Banners to the page, possibly even to the actual layout handle of the product you're trying to target on that page specifically. Most often this is done in major ecommerce sites (think Newegg) by promoting the relevant Shopping Cart Price Rule coupon code on the category page itself. I've split-test this method previously with great results and a 10% lift in add-to-cart.